# Collapsible with content-dependent expanded size

Tags: javascript, css

I coded a collapsible button using both CSS and JS, and I would like to place a button nested inside another one.

Is it possibile to dynamically adapt the height of the first/external button so that, when the second/internal button is opened, the height of the first one is increased by the height of the second one?

Here is the code I'm working on

```js
coll = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
conn = document.getElementsByClassName("con");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].setAttribute('data-id', 'con' + i);
    conn[i].setAttribute('id', 'con' + i);
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('data-id'));
        if (content.style.maxHeight) {
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.col {
  cursor: help;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: green;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
  transition: .3s;
}

.con {
  padding: 0 18px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 3px inset rgba(0,0,0,0.60);
}
```

```html
Does <button class=col>this</button> work?
  <div class=con>
    <p>Yes!</p>
    And what about <button class=col>this</button>?
      <div class=con>
      <p>Yes, but below text is gone!</p>
      </div>
  <p>bye bye</p>
  </div>
There is something to fix.
```

---

### EDIT: LAZY SOLUTION

In the javascript replace `content.scrollHeight` with a high value such as `9999`.

**Drawback**: when the button is opened, the transition from 0 to height starts immediately and is super fast since the space to cover is a lot; when the button is closed, the transition starts at max-height (not the actual height) so visually nothing happens from max-height to actual height, resulting in a delay.

```js
coll = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
conn = document.getElementsByClassName("con");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].setAttribute('data-id', 'con' + i);
    conn[i].setAttribute('id', 'con' + i);
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('data-id'));
        if (content.style.maxHeight) {
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = 9999 + "px";
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.col {
  cursor: help;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: green;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
  transition: .3s;
}

.con {
  padding: 0 18px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 3px inset rgba(0,0,0,0.60);
}
```

```html
Does <button class=col>this</button> work?
  <div class=con>
    <p>Yes!</p>
    And what about <button class=col>this</button>?
      <div class=con>
      <p>And the transition is super fast</p>
      </div>
  <p>Yes but there is a delay if you close it</p>
  </div>
There is something to fix.
```

I think the true solution is in [this page](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/#article-header-id-3), but I'm not able to adapt it to my case.

Answer (score 0):

> No need to calculate dynamic height.
>   [Example with button inside button](http://jsfiddle.net/pw1xs73m/)

```
{}
```

Comment: Accordion is a different object with respect to the collapsible button that I coded. Is it possibile to customize the accordion so that it behaves like it (that is the button can be a word in a sentence and when clicked the content is showed in a given point of the text without moving the text between the button and the content)? I already tried to customize the accordion to meet my needs, but did not succeed, that's why I ended up with the collapsible button.